# How does underscore.js create aliases for functions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

For example, `_.each` has an alias of `_.forEach`.

I can call `[1, 2, 3].forEach(alter)`, but when I call `[1, 2, 3].each(alert)`, it says

> TypeError: [1, 2, 3].each is not a function

I didn't find a definition of `forEach` in the source, so how does underscore.js do this?

Comment: Underscore doesn't extend the `Array` prototype. These are different functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is not the same as `_.forEach` or `_.each` for that matter. The standard `[].forEach` is a native function that is part of the `Array` API since ES5. (Its on the `Array` prototype)

In case of `_.forEach`, it doesn't actually use the `[].forEach` method to make it backwards compatible (pre ES5) so it just uses a `for` loop instead.

As far as aliases, Underscore creates aliases by pointing multiple variables to the same thing.

You can see all of this clearly in [section 20](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-20) of the annotated source:

```
// alias _.each and _.forEach to point to the same function
_.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
    // ...
    if (isArrayLike(obj)) {
      // use a for loop to perform the iteration
      for (i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
        iteratee(obj[i], i, obj);
      }
    } else {
    // ...
```

Here's a simple example of what underscore is doing:

```js
var _ = {};                                     // create our dummy Underscore object    
_.each = _.forEach = function(arr, callback) {  // alias _.each and _.forEach to loop and do callbacks
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    callback(arr[i], i);
  }
}

var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
_.each(a, function(item, index) {
  console.log(index + ': ' + item);
});
```